# NetCore 3.1 PostAsync CustomHeaders not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have several RESTful services that working with each other. In one scenario I want to post some data from one service to another service and I want to attach some information in Header of the request. I saw several cases to do this and in the end I came up with this workaround:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri(service2Address),
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))
};

httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("myCustomHeaderKey", "myCustomHeaderValue");

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

With these lines of code, a `Post` request sent, but in `service2` when I want to get the headers from request, there is no sign of `myCustomHeaderKey` in headers collection. I inspect `Request.Headers` in Visual Studio Watch and even try to get custom header with `Request.Headers["myCustomHeaderKey"]`. So what's wrong here?

**EDIT 1**

 This implementation in based on this [tutorial](https://massivescale.com/custom-headers-with-httpclient/).

Comment: Why don't you add the header here; `var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri(service2Address),
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))
};`

Comment: Hi @CasperDijkstra, that makes no difference to the output when add header in initialization of `httpRequestMessage` or after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed code like yours. Have created Two Asp.net core 3.1 project with standart template. One service is starting localhost:44320 and other localhost:44300
localhost:44320/PostService wrote the your codes.

[image]

Then get this url with browser. localhost:44320/weatherforecast/IncomeService function is like below

[image]

Finally i put breakpoint to where get request header. Result is like below

[image]

There is a not a problem. Maybe you use change request header middleware. Or if you are using something like nginx. this problem  maybe nginx configuration.